# Python unable to attach csv to email

Tags: python, csv, smtplib

I'm kind of a beginner in programming. With Python (3.5) I'm trying to create a script that scrapes a table from the web and writes a csv that is to be sent by email to a recipient. Thanks to various questions here at stvrflw I've managed to go nearly all the way.
Problem, though, my csv-attachment is empty?!? What am I missing??
Thanks!

```
....
#code above is to scrape info and create csv specified below. Works just fine!

        header="Date;Index;Country;%;+/-;Latest;High;Low;%1mon;%3mon;%6mon;%year;%1yr;Time"
    file=open(os.path.expanduser("Windex"+dte+".csv"),"wb")
    file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))
    file.write(bytes(kdata, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))

    SUBJECT="Windex"+dte

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'xxx@xxx.com'
    msg['To'] = 'xxx@xxx.com'
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT

    files= ['Windex'+dte+'.csv']

    for f in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open(f,"rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(os.path.basename(f)))
        msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('xxx','xxx')
    server.sendmail('xxx', 'xxx', msg.as_string())
```